# Sound issue in arecord

Tags: server, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a cron job that runs the following script once a day:

```
cd /home/me/myaudiodir
chmod 777 /dev/snd
chmod 777 /dev/snd/*
echo "/dev/snd/*:" > audiorec.log
ls -al /dev/snd >> audiorec.log
echo "/dev/snd:" >> audiorec.log
ls -al /dev | grep snd >> audiorec.log
echo "arecord -l:" >> audiorec.log
arecord -l >> audiorec.log
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------" >> audiorec.log
arecord -D hw:SIZHENG,0 -f S16_LE -r 44100 -d 28800 camera/audio-`date +%A`.wav 1>> audiorec.log 2>> audiorec.log
echo Bye! >> audiorec.log
```

The equipment is a microphone SIZHENG.

However, when it runs, it gives an error, which may be seen in the file `audiorec.log`:

```
/dev/snd/*:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root      300 Feb 13 18:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root     4080 Feb 13 18:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       60 Feb 13 18:54 by-id
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       80 Feb 13 18:54 by-path
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  2 Feb 13 11:51 controlC0
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  9 Feb 13 18:54 controlC1
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  4 Feb 13 21:19 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  3 Feb 13 21:19 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  5 Feb 13 11:51 pcmC0D1c
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  6 Feb 13 11:51 pcmC0D2c
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  7 Feb 13 11:51 pcmC0D3c
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  8 Feb 13 17:41 pcmC0D4p
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116, 10 Feb 13 18:54 pcmC1D0c
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  1 Feb 13 11:51 seq
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116, 33 Feb 13 11:51 timer
/dev/snd:
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root         300 Feb 13 18:54 snd
arecord -l:
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ICH6 [Intel ICH6], device 0: Intel ICH [Intel ICH6]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: ICH6 [Intel ICH6], device 1: Intel ICH - MIC ADC [Intel ICH6 - MIC ADC]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: ICH6 [Intel ICH6], device 2: Intel ICH - MIC2 ADC [Intel ICH6 - MIC2 ADC]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: ICH6 [Intel ICH6], device 3: Intel ICH - ADC2 [Intel ICH6 - ADC2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SIZHENG [SIZHENG], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
-----------------------------------------------------------
arecord: main:788: audio open error: Device or resource busy
Bye!
```

As may be seen, the error is `arecord: main:788: audio open error: Device or resource busy`. I have also `pulseaudio` installed...

I searched in the `syslog` and I obtained:

```
Feb 13 23:00:01 server pulseaudio[2325]: [pulseaudio] server-lookup.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
Feb 13 23:00:01 server pulseaudio[2325]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

When I try to run `arecord` from the command-line, sometimes it runs, other times, it gives the above error. However, after I run play a song with `aplay` it appears to function well...

EDIT:
I tried setting exit-idle-time to 20 in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf, but without the desired result. Again, the job gave the same error.
I would prefer to use a nicer command-line interface than PulseAudio.

Answer (score 1):

PulseAudio stops when it has not been used for a certain time. You can make the time shorter with the `exit-idle-time` setting in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`.

Alternatively, use PulseAudio for recording.

Comment: I tried setting exit-idle-time to 20 in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf, but without the desired result. Again, the job gave the same error.
I would prefer to use a nicer command-line interface than PulseAudio.

Comment: I countinue not to manage to record audio with cron jobs. Sometimes even in the usual command-line it gives the same error. Which command `pacmd`or `pactl` should I execute before `arecord` in order to solve this problem?